# How to make files in S3 private if session has expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some images stored in Amazon S3 bucket. I am pointing to them in my web pages using `<img src>`.

I don't want the images to be viewable when a user is not logged in. Can I make it private from my backend when a user logs out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Presigned Object URLs** to get the images from a private S3 bucket. These presigned URLs are valid only for a specified duration. Here is a basic example of how to generate these presigned URLs using boto3 in Python:

```
import boto3

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = <access_key_id>
AWS_SECRET_KEY = <secret_key>
AWS_REGION = <region_name>

client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    region_name = AWS_REGION
)

PRESIGNED_DOWNLOAD_URL = client.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod = 'get_object',  
    Params = {
        'Bucket': AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        'Key': FILE_NAME,
    }, 
    ExpiresIn = 3600,
)
print(PRESIGNED_DOWNLOAD_URL)
```

Here, you just have to provide AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_KEY, AWS_REGION of the bucket, AWS_BUCKET_NAME and the FILE_NAME you want to download. ExpiresIn=3600 is given in seconds. So, this URL will be valid for 60 minutes.

Rest of the part has to be handled by your application. That is when a user logs in, generate presigned URLs and get images from the URL in your template. Otherwise, don't render the images in your template.

Answer (score 3):

You should:

- Keep the objects in Amazon S3 private (not publicly accessible)
- Have your application generate [Pre-Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

A Pre-Signed URL grants time-limited access to a private object in S3. Once the time period expires, it is no longer accessible.

Your application is responsible for authenticating users and determining whether they are permitted to access an object. If so, the application should generate the Pre-Signed URL. The URL can then be included in HTML the same as a normal URL (eg in an `<img>` tag).